# Why JBoss Comes BundledWith Tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss

My question is why JBoss is bundled with Tomcat? I thought JBoss was supposed to provide all the Java EE functionality. Can someone please provide some clear explanation as to why JBoss needs to use Tomcat?

Comment: So, can I consider 'JBoss Web' as a module that includes Tomcat as one of its component, but provides much more features?  That seems to be what JBoss claims.

Also, do I in general need to care about whether I'm working with Tomcat or 'JBoss Web' or I can ignore this issue and just use JBoss without paying too much attention to how the pages are served?

Answer (score 4):

[JBoss AS 7](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/) doesn't use Tomcat directly, but instead uses [JBoss Web](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/) which is based on Tomcat. It provides the Servlet/JSP container for JBoss AS.

Comment: So, what versions of JBoss use Tomcat? I know that JBoss 4 and 5 for sure use Tomcat. So, this means that JBoss AS 7 has totally replaced Tomcat with JBoss Web?

Comment: Yes, in JBoss AS JBoss Web is used and not Tomcat. Looks like https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS is a good starting point for the versions.

Comment: Thanks for your replay James.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is forked to JBoss Web. The EE specification does not say that the author must be the same for all implementations of subspecs.

Maybe interesting for you: 
You can see on the following page what version of Tomcat (forked to JBoss Web) is used in which JBoss AS version:

[Versions of Tomcat / JBoss Web in JBoss AS](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS)